# Form not submitting when "multipart/form-data" is used in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, multipartform-data, enctype

When `enctyp="multipart/form-data"` is used in **Laravel** view page with `method="post"` and `action="route({{}})"`, the clicking the submit button doesn't even trigger the controller method. When i use raw php it works fine. In local environment laravel works fine. But when deployed in live server it causes a "site can not be reached, connection was reset" error.

Using **Apache** in Linode server.

Comment: just post the html code

Comment: Is it your first time using Laravel ? Shwo us your **routing** please !